# How to format this date string "2013-08-26T12:00:00.000" in the following way: "2013-08-26 12:00:00" to Date object in java?

Tags: java, date

I am writing a converter method that would parse an xml string data to java objects. But i am not able to parse dates to date objects.
How to format this date string "2013-08-26T12:00:00.000"  in the following way: "2013-08-26 12:00:00" to Date object in java?

Edited to add the below code snippet.
Here is what I tried to do.

```
public Object fromString(String str) {
    DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateInstance();
    try {
        Date date = dateFormat.parse(str);
        return date;
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: It might help if you show a code snippet of what you have tried that is not working.

Comment: Here is what I tried to do.
Passing the above mentioned date as string(str) here.

public Object fromString(String str){

DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateInstance();
try {
 Date date = dateFormat.parse(str);
 return date;
 } 
 catch (ParseException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
 }

}

Comment: If you stress the point that you have different input patterns (allowed in XML-schema) then more people will see that your question is not so trivial and well-answered in many other SO-threads.

Comment: @codingNubie Edit your question to add code snippet, rather than a comment. Notice the `edit` link to the lower left of your Question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to process XML-date-time-strings which are allowed to be of variable precision (sometimes leaving out second- or fraction-part or timezone-offset) the use of `SimpleDateFormat` is not a good option because then you would only have one pattern. Not flexible.

**Alternative for XML:**

```
String xml = "2013-08-26T12:00:00.000"; // maybe optionally with additional timezone offset
javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory factory = javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory.newInstance();
XMLGregorianCalendar xmlGregCal = factory.newXMLGregorianCalendar(xml);
java.util.Date d = xmlGregCal.toGregorianCalendar().getTime();

SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
String output = outputFormat.format(d);
```

Watch also out for some overloaded methods to change the timezone settings for parsing and formatting - see the javadoc.

Comment: Works perfect!!!
All the dates of my xml files are converted to date objects. Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 3):

You should google these things first.
Here you go:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    String inFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS";
    String outFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(inFormat);
    try {
        Date d = sdf.parse("2013-08-26T12:00:00.000");
        sdf.applyPattern(outFormat);
        System.out.println(sdf.format(d));
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // handle appropriately
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It works but I have multiple date formats in different XML files. One has yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z' while other has "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS". It fails with other formats...

Comment: This is an example to show how to use date formats. It is obvious you will be accepting the dateString, inFormat and outFormat as method arguments. At least try something from your side, hope you don't expect to be spoon fed here.

Answer (score 2):

You can parse **any** Date-like string to Date object (as long as the the string represents a valid date) using http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

There is **no** point in re-formatting the String.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String original = "2013-08-26T12:00:00.000";
    Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.S").parse(original);
    String format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(date);
    System.out.printf("Before: %s\nAfter: %s\n", original, format);
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
Before: 2013-08-26T12:00:00.000
After:  2013-08-26 12:00:00
```